Why does my system have a 0 byte block device?
I'm using a linux live disk on a thinkpad laptop with a single unformatted hard drive.
lsblk is report a 0 byte block device of type disk:
# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     1G  1 loop /nix/.ro-store
sda      8:0    1  57.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1   1.1G  0 part /iso
└─sda2   8:2    1     3M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1     0B  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk 

sda is the boot linux live disk and sdc is the laptop's hard drive. sdb should not exist.
dmesg has a few logs related to sdb:
# dmesg | grep sdb
[    7.411121] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Media removed, stopped polling
[    7.411315] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

I can delete the device:
echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/delete

But it returns after a reboot. What is this block device and why does it exist?
EDIT: The computer does have an SD Card reader.

Does this machine have an SD card reader or similar?

Oh actually it does have one. Would that be the cause?

Since sdb says "Media removed" and the kernel detects it as "SCSI removable disk", it is likely this is your SD card reader.
If you put a card in it then the size for sdb should update to reflect the size of the card.
eg on my machine lsblk shows
sdc                   8:32   1     0B  0 disk  

I insert an SD card in it and in sudo dmesg I see
[94255.136132] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 122241024 512-byte logical blocks: (62.6 GB/58.3 GiB)
[94255.138370] sdc: detected capacity change from 0 to 122241024

And now lsblk shows
sdc                   8:32   1  58.3G  0 disk  

Next I sudo eject /dev/sdc and remove the card, and now it's back to 0B output again.
